# Consuming Swift class in Objective C - Only String variables accessible

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsobject

This is my `Swift` class :

```
@objc public class UserParentMessage : NSObject {
   public var HasAttachments: Int?
   public var UserParentMessageId: Int?
   public var LatestReplyDateTime: String?
   public var LatestReplyDateTimeStr: String?
   public var NumberOfReplies: Int?
   public var ReadOn: String?
   public var SenderUserId: Int?
   public var Subject: String?
   public var TotalMessageCount: Int?
   public var sender: Sender?
}
```

In `Objective C` class, I have created it's object as :

```
UserParentMessage *userParentMessage = [UserParentMessage new];
```

I am able to access all `String` types (like **LatestReplyDateTime, Subject**) but not the other types. Probably doing some stupid mistake. What might that be ?

Comment: what the isue u faced,..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : I can access LatestReplyDateTime by userParentMessage. LatestReplyDateTime but when I do so for HasAttachments, it doesn't show up. Giving one of the examples.

Comment: Consider not to use optionals as a *don't-care* alibi. `HasAttachments` is supposed to be a non-optional boolean and `NumberOfReplies` and `TotalMessageCount` are supposed to be non-optional, too. What is the practical purpose of a counter of *nil*?

Comment: @vadian : So instead should I use "public var HasAttachments: Int = 0" ?

Comment: Yes, or `Bool = false` because actually it has only two states:has or has not attachments.

Comment: @vadian : Similar to c# then.

Comment: I have no idea of c#. ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure since I never combined Swift and Objective-C in a single app, but maybe (just maybe) Objective-C isn't recognizing Sender and Int types. Try to use AnyObject and NSNumber instead.